Runing JS on Chrome extension as if Running on Debug Terminal
I am trying to create a text area on my chrome extension's popup page, and have a button that allows the user to write and run their own JS function there. I also would like to run it as if it is running on the current page, i.e. using the current page's <script>. Is there any possible solution for that?
